# Re: Do chips really need multiple values of decoupling capacitors?

Tags: discussion

Linked here: [Do chips really need multiple values of decoupling capacitors? [duplicate]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/400683/158814)

This question is different from the one that it's supposedly a duplicate of. The original question wasn't specifically asking about the logic of using different values in the same package. I don't know what else I need to say. Good conversation will flow from this, can someone please un-flag it. The title may also need to be edited.

Comment: I agree the Q should be reopened, but "good conversations" is not the goal of the site, so won't be what motivates reopening.

Comment: I did find an old question that addresses the question of parallel capacitors in the same package: [Will a 0402 0.01 µF ceramic capacitor next to a 0402 0.1 µF ceramic capacitor have any power decoupling benefits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/25280/6334).

Answer (score -4):

The question might not be, but the answers are

Comment: There's only one answer and I agree it's poor. The question was marked duplicate almost immediately which probably stifled discussion. There's certainly a good answer to be posted, were the question not flagged.

Comment: Agreed, we won't see what kind answers the question could get if we don't re-open it.